# How to transfer EXM campaign and mail between environments?

Tags: exm

My customer has prepared an automated campaign on the test environment. The campaign is used in a Form and is working fine on that test environment.

I need to transfer the form and the campaign to the production environment. How?

I packaged the form items and the related items in Email/Messages and installed them on production. The items are installed properly and the form is ok, but I do not get my campaign in the EXM admin..  what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to the email message through the content editor. And click on "open exm", next click on "Full Email Campaign", go to the delivery tab and then you need to de-activate and re-activate the email message.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Email Experience Manager messages relies on analytics. When you transfer it by package, no analytics information is transferred. (e.g.: AutomationRanges and Automation states Mongo collections data).

For example when you look on Sitecore.Demo for ExM, [it comes with data](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo/tree/master/analytics/MongoData/analytics) that should be exported to Mongo to makes it work properly.

How to overcome it:

1. Migrate also analytics data. (complex and risky way)
2. Move ExM campaign to initial workflow state(Draft). And click "Deploy" button. It should create required data in analytics db.

P.S. ExM campaign creates separate campaign(under /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Campaigns/Emails) and engagement plan items(under /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Engagement Plans/Email Campaign) for each campaign. Make sure that you have added them to package as you haven't listed it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I also had to include some items from the `Marketing Control Panel/Campaigns/Emails/..` that were related to my message. Otherwise there was a missing link in my mail item. Just wanted to add this to make the solution complete.

After that was done, the "Open EXM" button on the item in the content editor (as suggested by Bart) worked perfectly. That opened my campaign in EXM and after re-activating, the mail appeared in the EXM overview.

Comment: that was mentioned in PS of my answer. Also you need engagement plan. Without engagement plan you will be able to see message, but you would not be able to track results of ExM campaign.(How many users have opened it, clicked on link, etc.)