# Sitecore package of EXM automated message

Tags: exm, packages

Sitecore 9.1.1

What files need to be included in Package designer if I want to export my EXM automated messages from environment X to Y?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to include the item with the message and all the needed parents. The message item is in the email root (could be `/sitecore/content/Email`). Within the `Messages` folder you have folders based on the date (year/month/...). You might want to include those (without all children) to make sure the path to the message item exists.

Once you have those in the package, you can install it on the new environment. Verify if the item exists. It won't show up in EXM though - you need to open the message in EXM (from the content editor) and re-activate it to get it visible there as explained in this Q/A: [How to transfer EXM campaign and mail between environments?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/16040/237)